# Sass and rounding down numbers. Can this be configured?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, responsive-design

Is there any way for me to modify the way that Sass will handle decimal places? I saw a few people saying that Sass will dynamically do the (target/parent)*100 calculation needed for responsive layouts, and output the result at compile time. It even has a percentage function, which will essentially take the two values and do this.

Alas, Sass will only ever give me 3 decimal places. My understanding up to this point has been that in some cases, this may not be a sufficient degree of accuracy for all browsers to properly display the layout without any hiccups.

Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this?

**EDIT**

Solved. Incase anyone else is interested, I managed to accomplish what I wanted in Sass's number.rb, changing the value of @precision. This alters the way all floats are output.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Compass, you can easily specify the precision in your project file (config.rb) without hacking the core:

```
Sass::Script::Number.precision = 8
```

For more information see [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/Number.html#precision-class_method)

Answer (score 5):

It can also be configured using `--precision` in the commandline, see [SASS Changelog, version 3.1.8](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#318).

Should also add that if you want to edit `@precision` in `numbers.rb` directly, you can find `numbers.rb` (at least on OS X), here:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/user-gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.1.10/lib/sass/script
```

1.8 and 3.1.10 should of course be replaced with your (preferably the latest) version numbers.

Comment: Have you managed to get this to work? When I try "sass --precision 6" Nothing happens.

Comment: @Jon the syntax is slightly different: `--precision=6` ... so instead of ` ` you need a `=`

Answer (score 1):

First set [your default precision](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/Number.html#precision-class_method) to the highest precision you're going to need in your project.

Then, use a function like the one below (which is based on [this function by Takeru Suzuki](https://gist.github.com/terkel/4373420)) to customize the number of decimals at the level of individual properties.

**Code :**

```
@function decimal-round ($number, $digits: 0, $mode: round) {
    $n: 1;
    // $number must be a number
    @if type-of($number) != number {
        @warn '#{ $number } is not a number.';
        @return $number;
    }
    // $digits must be a unitless number
    @if type-of($digits) != number {
        @warn '#{ $digits } is not a number.';
        @return $number;
    } @else if not unitless($digits) {
        @warn '#{ $digits } has a unit.';
        @return $number;
    }
    @if $digits > 0 {
        @for $i from 1 through $digits {
            $n: $n * 10;
        }
    }
    @if $mode == round {
        @return round($number * $n) / $n;
    } @else if $mode == ceil {
        @return ceil($number * $n) / $n;
    } @else if $mode == floor {
        @return floor($number * $n) / $n;
    } @else {
        @warn '#{ $mode } is undefined keyword.';
        @return $number;
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
decimal-round(0.333)    => 0
decimal-round(0.333, 1) => 0.3
decimal-round(0.333, 2) => 0.33
decimal-round(0.666)    => 1
decimal-round(0.666, 1) => 0.7
decimal-round(0.666, 2) => 0.67
```