# SASS calculation rounding - configurating the number of decimals with Web Workbench and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, sass, decimal, rounding, visual-studio-extensions

In SASS you can usually configure how many decimals you want in your calculations (see [Sass and rounding down numbers. Can this be configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672473/sass-and-rounding-down-numbers-can-this-be-configured)).

This is handy, as especially Chrome sometimes have some weird rounding errors.

I'm currently working with SASS in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 with Mindscape Web Workbench (http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench). Do anybody know how you configure these settings in such an environment?

(I've also posted the question over at Mindscape's own support forum: http://www.mindscapehq.com/forums/thread/673536).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mindscape got back on the forum, and you can do this through a "compile option directive". Simply put this in the top of your SASS file:

```
//* scss-compile-options: --precision 8
```